# How to pass userid from one table to another table in spring mvc using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring security for the login. I have the `User.java` which contains user-details.

```
 @Entity(name = "user_table")
 //@Table(name = "user_table")
 public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "email" ,unique = true)
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String userPassword;    

    //getter and setters
}
```

I'm getting the whole data of the current user from the table by using spring security. This is the code:

```
   public User findUserByEmail(String email) {

       List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
       try{
             users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user_table where email= ?").setParameter(0, email).list();

            System.out.println("user is " +users);
       }catch(Exception e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              e.printStackTrace();
       }

       if (users.size() > 0) {
             return users.get(0);
       } else {
                return null;
      }
  }



    @Override
    public User getCurrentUser() {

            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                            .getAuthentication();
            User currentUser = new User();
            if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
                    System.out.println("User has authorities: "
                                    + userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    System.out.println("USERNAME::  "+userDetails.getUsername());
                    currentUser = findUserByEmail(userDetails
                                    .getUsername());
                    System.out.println("currentUser    "+currentUser);
                    System.out.println("currentUser    "+currentUser.getUserId());

                    return currentUser;
            }
            return null;
    }
```

What I want is to send the user id which I'm getting from `currentUser.getUserId()` to some other method. In that method I'm mapping to some other table like `user_detail` table where id is primary key. By sending id, I will get the other user_details which are not present in the user_table.

This is my `UserDetail`:

```
@Entity(name = "user_detail")
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class UserDetail {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String userId;

    //some other details like Address .
    //getter and setter.
}
```

From controller I'm calling the above method like this:

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
User user=userDao.getCurrentUser();
String userId = user.getUserId();
System.out.println(userId);
UserDetail u=userDao.findUserById(userId);
```

and this is the method where I pass the current user id :

```
public UserDetail findUserById(String id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<String> users = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{

        users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user_detail where id= ?").setParameter(0, id).list();

        System.out.println("user is " +users);
        }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (users.size() > 0) {
                return null;
        } else {
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Now the result I'm getting here is null . Like user is null. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `if (users.size() > 0) {return null;} else { return null;}` - you're always returning `null` from `findUserById` method.

Comment: @Daniel..ok thats is one error.another any error because its not printing anything from the user_detail table.

Comment: see i am getting output as - user id [] like this.means its not getting the right id in the method.thats why its printing blank.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. Just to point out some of them:

1. `UserService userService = new UserService();` - you're manually creating the service object and not letting Spring-MVC injecting it into your controller, i.e. :

   `@Autowired
   private UserService userService ;`
2. `UserDAO` should be injected in your service, and not called from your controller :

   ```
   class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

       @Autowired
       private UserDAO userDAO;
   }
   ```
3. All operations from your controller should call services methods and not DAO's methods. The service should use the DAO for database access. i.e.

   `UserDetail u=userDao.findUserById(userId);`

   should become

   `UserDetail u = userService.findUserById(userId);`

and in your service :

```
class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

      @Autowire
      private UserDAO userDAO;

      @Override
      public UserDetail findUserById(Long userId){
             return userDAO.findUserById(userId);
      }
}
```

4. `if (users.size() > 0) {
               return null;
       } else {
               return null;
       }`

   is always returning `null`. Should be :

   ```
    if (`users.isEmpty()){ 
         return users.get(0);
    }else { return null;}
   ```
5. `users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user_detail where id= ?").setParameter(0, id).list();`

   Your query is wrong. You should use your current bean class name and not the table name in your query, i.e. `createQuery("FROM UserDetail WHERE id = ?")`